# Cordova with Angular, how to get deviceready event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I have been having various issues with the device ready event, from the `deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds` error to not having the plugins work.

From what I understand from my research, the following is required (please correct me if i'm wrong):

- angular must be loaded before the `deviceready` event or it wont pick it up
- cordova.js must be loaded in less than 5 seconds

So my question is - how do I get cordova.js loaded as quick as possible while making it wait for angular to be ready for the `deviceready` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use manual bootstrapping to get it work (perfectly)

```
function bootstrapAngular() {
    var domElement = document.querySelector('html');
    angular.bootstrap(domElement, ['appName']);
}
if (document.URL.indexOf('http://') === -1 && document.URL.indexOf('https://') === -1) {
    // URL: Running in Cordova/PhoneGap
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", bootstrapAngular, false);
```

the if because my app is accessible form browser (either "http://" or "https://") and cordova("file://").

Comment: So do you set the event listener -> load cordova -> load angular on deviceready? Do you load the cordova.js before the angular.js or does it not matter?

Comment: doesnt matter at all since angular wont start until cordova fires the device ready event. just place this at the bottom of your index.html and remove your ng-app="" attribute

Comment: ah rats, I guess I have been on the wrong track with thinking it is angular causing it.  I'm doing what you suggest and I still get device not ready after 5 seconds if I include cordova.js early or no plugins work if I include it late.  But thanks, you answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Load cordova.js after loading angular, and error 'deviceready not fired after 5 seconds' you will face only on desktop browser, instead when you will try on actual device or emulator, the event will fire.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Corvoda Mocks](https://github.com/pbernasconi/chrome-cordova) to simulate the device's state on Chrome for testing your app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load AngularJs before Cordova.

If you want, here's a working seed:
  https://github.com/marioaleogolsat/cordova-angular-angularMaterial-seed

Just remember that some plugins can't be used in a emulation, so use cordova run  --device to make sure that anything is working properly.